# There are 3 consecutive even numbers given to you. The sum of the first, second, and twice the third is 46. What is the second number?

Tags: analysis

I've tried changing the ordering around and seeing if that makes it easier for me, but I'm pretty much stumped.

This was assigned as an extra credit "challenge problem" for us, and I feel like it's really easy and I'm just missing something obvious here. I can see how to solve it, but for any credit, we need to do it algebraically. That's where I get stuck.

Anybody have a hint or way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: you can represent the 3 numbers as $x$, $x+2$, and $x+4$, with $x$ being the first number, $x+2$ the second, and $x+4$ the third.

Comment: Oh! This makes sense.
Thank you! It was pretty obvious. I don't know how I couldn't figure that out, lol.

Comment: @Stretch Maniac \\ No, you cannot. For the numbers to be even, $x$ has to be even, as well.

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi The lack of solution is apparent when 9 is discovered as the sole solution. Besides, the existence of a solution is not as important as the concept itself. Also, substituting $2x$ for $x$ merely changes the check when the solution is found from "is the answer even?" to "is the answer an integer?".

Comment: @Stretch Maniac \\ I didn't feel as though I had the right to change the terms of the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are required to be even, as stated by the OP (@Katie K.), then the problem has no solution.
Suppose the numbers are $2x-2$, $2x$ and $2x+2$. The required sum is
$\begin{matrix}
2x-2\\
2x\\
2x+2\\
2x+2\\
\end{matrix}=8x+2=46$. This gives $5.5$ as the value for $x$ and $11$ as the value of the middle number. $11$ is not even, contrary to the OP's requirement.